# Trailhead LWC Basics - ERROR running force:source:deploy: Deploy failed. - E_Bikes1 Not Available to Deploy for this Org

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, deployment, trailhead

I am completing the [Lightning Web Components -> Push and Deploy Lightning Web Component Files](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics/push-lightning-web-component-files) challenge and am getting the "ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Deploy failed." error as many others on this and other forums have discussed when executing the following command

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default -u ebikesDE
```

for step 9 in the [Installing E-Bikes using a Developer Edition Org](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc#installing-e-bikes-using-a-developer-edition-org).

I initially created the bikeCard folder and html/js/xml files manually but saw someone suggest to do it programmatically so I used the command

```
sfdx force:lightning:component:create -n bikeCard -d force-app/main/default/lwc --type lwc
```

However I am still getting the same error. When I go to the deployment status logs, I get this issue with deploying E_Bikes1 folder and files to my org. 
[image]
[image]

Is this some issue with mobile files not able to deploy to the dev hub org? I haven't seen any other discussion about this specific error log message.

Answer (score 0):

You might be deploying to an org that does not have my domain enabled.

You can create a my domain from the set up and deploy the my domain to all users.

This [document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_overview.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) explains how one can enable my domain

You might also need to enable Salesforce communities.

Comment: I have my domain enabled on the org I am deploying to.

Comment: Also may be you require communities enabled and sites enabled for your org